# Can I pipe lshw warnings to /dev/null when I run it as a standard user?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, piping

I'm trying to create an alias for getting memory on my machine, currently I have `alias mem="lshw | grep size | awk -F: '{print $2}'"`, and when I run it as a non-super user, I get the following warning message:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
      size: 23GiB
```

I'm not worried about the results being potentially incomplete, in fact when I diff the output when running as root vs a standard user, it's exactly the same. Does anybody know how to get rid of these warnings? I tried piping stderr to /dev/null, but that didn't work. Does anyone else know how to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I interest you in

```
alias mem='free -g | grep Mem | awk '\''{print $2 " GiB"}'\'
```

`free -m` will give MiB; you can change the " GiB" part to whatever you want (or remove it).

I don't have `lshw` installed on my machine, so I can't help you debug your version, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias mem="lshw 2> /dev/null| grep size | awk -F: '{print $2}'"
```

Alternatively you can use free or read from `/proc/meminfo`

```
cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemTotal
```

Comment: That works, thanks! This makes sense because stderr is printed to the screen before everything is piped to grep, so even if I try to pipe it to /dev/null later, it's still on screen before that. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you piped to dev/null, but this works for me:

```
lshw 2> /dev/null | grep size | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Ignoring that there are other tools more suited to getting the memory, if there is something you need and lshw is your only option, you would be better suited to use -json or -xml output and use a tool to parse it like jq or xmllint. The version of lshw on my distro outputs invalid json that can't be parsed, but does have valid xml output.

This would accomplish your goal, although the path may very well be different for you:

```
lshw -xml 2> /dev/null | xmllint --xpath '/list/node/node/node[@id="memory"]/size/text()' -
```

Answer (score 0):

Or add a one grep:

`... | grep "size:"`

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, it still gives the error. I appreciate the feedback, but when I try it I get the following: `lshw | grep size | awk -F: '{print $2}' | grep GiB`, I get the output:



`WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
 23GiB`

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now, @Logu helped me understand it because it's printed as stderr from lshw directly but it's printed to the screen before we grep, so we can't grep again to get just the size without the error because it's already printed to the screen.